# Java: Creating Simple Lottery Number Generator

Tags: java

I must create a simple Java lottery number generator modelled off of Lotto 6/49 (Ontario, Canada). The user is asked how many tickets they wish to generate. The tickets must be in ascending order of numbers and have no duplicates. For example, if I wanted 3 tickets, an output may be:

```
8 12 17 25 32 47
6 10 21 30 39 42
1 8 16 37 45 49
```

Problems arise when trying to sort the numbers. We are taught to use a bubble sort, however my duplicate check is not working properly so I will end up with an output like so:

```
8 18 29 29 29 29
4 12 18 18 24 24
4 12 18 24 46 46
```

My code is as follows:

```
// The "Lotto" class.
import java.awt.*;
import hsa.Console;

public class Lotto
{
    static Console c;           // The output console

public static void main (String[] args)
{
    c = new Console ();
    int t = 0;
    int num[];
    num = new int[10];

    c.println("How many Lotto 6/49 tickets do you wish to generate?");
    t = c.readInt();
    c.println("****************");

    for (int a = 1; a <= t; a++)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
        {
            num[i] = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
            for (int x = 1; x <= 6; x++) // duplicate check
            {
                for (int y = x + 1; y <= 7; y++)
                {
                    if (num[x] == num[y])
                    {
                        num[y] = (int)(Math.random() * 49 + 1);
                    }
                }
            } // end check
            for (int p = 1; p <=6; p++) // start sort
            {
                for (int q = 1; q <=7; q++)
                {
                    if (num[p] < num[q])
                    {
                        int temp = num[p];
                        num[p] = num[q];
                        num[q] = temp;
                    }
                }
            } // end sort
            c.print(num[i] + " ");
        }
    c.println();
    }       
} // main method
} // Lotto class
```

Any help into the matter or a solution would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You do know that Java provides a [`Array.sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int[])) method?

Comment: @UnholySheep yes, however we must use a bubble sort as it is in our notes and we have to apply those to our exercises.

Comment: And do you also have a reason for skipping the first element of the array (which is at index 0)? Or allocating an array of size 10 when you never access beyond the 8th element? Also you are always only printing a single element after sorting, so your output does not represent the actual state of the array

Comment: @UnholySheep I am following the examples/handouts we were given as best as possible and they all skip the first element and allocate more memory than necessary to the array. A sample program says _enter five numbers_ and our handout's solution is `num = new int[10]`.

Answer (score 1):

This is a poor abstraction.  I'd recommend embedding all the logic inside a class.  Object oriented programming is about abstraction, encapsulation, and hiding details.

Here's how I'd do it:

```
package gambling;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;

/**
 * Created by Michael
 * Creation date 3/21/2017.
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42932262/java-creating-simple-lottery-number-generator
 */
public class LottoTicket {

    public static final int DEFAULT_NUM_TICKETS = 10;
    public static final int DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE = 49;
    public static final int DEFAULT_NUM_VALUES = 6;
    private Random random;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numTickets = (args.length > 0) ? Integer.parseInt(args[0]) : DEFAULT_NUM_TICKETS;
        LottoTicket lottoTicket = new LottoTicket();
        for (int i = 0; i < numTickets; ++i) {
            System.out.println(lottoTicket.getNumbers(DEFAULT_NUM_VALUES, DEFAULT_MAX_VALUE));
        }
    }

    public LottoTicket() {
        this(null);
    }

    public LottoTicket(Long seed) {
        this.random = (seed != null) ? new Random(seed) : new Random();
    }

    public Set<Integer> getNumbers(int numValues, int maxValue) {
        Set<Integer> numbers = new TreeSet<>();
        while (numbers.size() < numValues) {
            numbers.add(this.random.nextInt(maxValue) + 1);
        }
        return numbers;
    }
}
```

Comment: While I agree with your answer I suspect you've just introduced a dozen new concepts that OP hasn't been taught yet! Also note OP's comment that the solution must use a bubble sort (which I suspect is the point of the exercise)

Comment: Consider it aspirational.  The idea is the same: embed it inside that class.  He can substitute all the stuff that's going on inside getNumbers() and replace it with something that matches his assignment and level.

Comment: Yep I guess something to aim for:-) I'll do the same in my own just for OP's possible interest!

Comment: @duffymo I fear sprinter was correct, I'm having trouble trying to understand your code (although I am genuinely trying). Part of the problem is I can't run it (we use _Ready to Program_ in my class) for some reason..

Comment: It's valid Java that runs without a problem for me on the Oracle JDK.  I can't speak to your situation.  The point is to add the code that you need inside the method getNumbers().  All the rest of the code will just work.  Consider it aspirational.  I'm sure you aren't using built-in collections like TreeSet yet, but you can read the docs to see how that works and figure out why I chose it.  What problem does it solve?  (Hint: No need to sort; no worries about duplicate entries.)

Answer (score 1):

Actually neither your bubble sort nor your duplicate check is working.

For the duplicate check, you are generating a new random number if you detect a duplicate but there's nothing stopping your code generating the same duplicate. Try changing `if (num[x] == num[y])` to `while (num[x] == num[y])`

For the bubble sort I think you've misunderstood the algorithm. The general form should be:

```
boolean changed = false;
do {
    for (int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        if (num[i] > num[i+1]) {
            // swap 
            changed = true;
        }
    }
} while (changed);
```

While I assume it's beyond the scope of your question, the entire set can be generated in one statement with Java 8:

```
int[] nums = random.ints(1, 50).distinct().limit(6).sorted().toArray();
```

This is interpreted as: generate an infinite stream of random numbers between 1 and 49, remove duplicates, get the first 6, sort them and return them as an array.

Comment: Thank you! I have fixed the duplicate check. However, I still cannot get my bubble sort to work. I have been trying to implement it after the duplicate check (my train of thought says generate numbers, check for duplicates, sort, output) however when using your algorithm, my program returns no numbers at all, only blank space.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

class LotoTicket {
  private static final int NUM_NUMBERS = 6;
  private static final int NUM_BALLS = 99;
  private static final Random random = new Random();
  private final int[] numbers;

  private LotoTicket(final int[] numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
  }

  public static LotoTicket generateTicket() {
    final int[] numbers = new int[NUM_NUMBERS];
    final List<Integer> ballPool = IntStream.range(1, 1 + NUM_BALLS)
      .mapToObj(i -> i)
      .collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMBERS; i++) {
      final int draw = random.nextInt(NUM_BALLS - i);
      numbers[i] = ballPool.remove(draw);
    }
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    return new LotoTicket(numbers);
  }

  public int[] getNumbers() {
    return numbers;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("LotoTicket{");
    sb.append("numbers=").append(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.println(LotoTicket.generateTicket());
    System.out.println(LotoTicket.generateTicket());
    System.out.println(LotoTicket.generateTicket());
  }
}
```

#### Edit

Here is a version that is java1.5 compliant and implements a simple bubble-sort:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Random;

class LotoTicket {
  private static final int NUM_NUMBERS = 6;
  private static final int NUM_BALLS = 99;
  private static final Random random = new Random();
  private final int[] numbers;

  private LotoTicket(final int[] numbers) {
    this.numbers = numbers;
  }

  public static LotoTicket generateTicket() {
    final int[] numbers = new int[NUM_NUMBERS];
    final List<Integer> ballPool = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_BALLS; i++) {
      ballPool.add(i, i + 1);
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_NUMBERS; i++) {
      final int draw = random.nextInt(NUM_BALLS - i);
      numbers[i] = ballPool.remove(draw);
    }
    bubbleSort(numbers);
    return new LotoTicket(numbers);
  }

  private static void bubbleSort(final int[] numbers) {
    if (numbers.length <= 1) {
      return;
    }
    boolean sorted;
    do {
      sorted = true;
      for (int i = 1; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        if (numbers[i - 1] > numbers[i]) {
          final int temp = numbers[i];
          numbers[i] = numbers[i - 1];
          numbers[i - 1] = temp;
          sorted = false;
        }
      }
    } while (sorted == false);
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("LotoTicket{");
    sb.append("numbers=").append(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    sb.append('}');
    return sb.toString();
  }

  public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.println(LotoTicket.generateTicket());
    System.out.println(LotoTicket.generateTicket());
    System.out.println(LotoTicket.generateTicket());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I am trying to test this but (as mentioned in another comment) my class uses the _Ready to Program_ IDE and if I try and implement this into it, the application has a meltdown and breaks. Will need to test this elsewhere.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the error you're seeing? Is there a specific version of java your class uses? Are there specific classes or constructs you may not use?